# last N days according to similar status using timestamp table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

sorry my english is bad
i have a question about of how can i get a measure for use with slice visor

i have a table with status like is showed here

maq Status  Timestamp
dev1    on  10/27/2021 10:20
dev1    on  10/27/2021 9:20
dev1    on  10/27/2021 8:20
dev1    on  10/27/2021 7:20
dev1    on  10/27/2021 6:20
dev1    on  10/26/2021 21:20
dev1    off 10/26/2021 20:20
dev1    off 10/26/2021 19:20
dev1    on  10/25/2021 11:20
dev1    on  10/25/2021 10:20
dev1    on  10/25/2021 9:20
dev1    on  10/25/2021 8:20
dev1    off 10/23/2021 9:20
dev1    off 10/23/2021 5:20
dev1    on  10/22/2021 23:20
dev1    on  10/22/2021 19:20
dev1    on  10/21/2021 19:20
dev1    on  10/21/2021 14:20
dev1    on  10/20/2021 17:20
dev1    on  10/20/2021 12:20
dev1    on  10/19/2021 20:20
dev1    on  10/19/2021 18:20
dev1    on  10/18/2021 9:20
dev1    on  10/18/2021 7:20
dev2    off 10/27/2021 10:20
dev2    off 10/27/2021 9:20
dev2    off 10/27/2021 8:20
dev2    off 10/27/2021 7:20

he idea is  first step is  group dev by date  and then compare with respect to total rows vs total status , if grand total by dev  is equal to total status off by dev  is true
note: status were replaced by 1 ( off) and 0 ( on)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fccnb.png)

after that ,we should have the output like is showed below using a slicer visor like dropdwon , when you select some day , we refer last n days with fully true day

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb5xF.png)

I hope it is understandable

thanks in advance any suggestion

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Could you format the data better and describe what the desired output is trying to show?

Comment: Hello user904963 , i did some change about od the question. my idea is  only get the devices that had same status( off) during  all time depending selected day

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your request correctly, a simple relationship between `Days Table` and `Status Table` should establish the connection, then you can just create a `Slicer` with `Value from the Days table`.

Now create `Table Visualization` where you will filter only `off` statuses and then filter actual days using the `slicer`.

[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFR5k.png)

[Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yAEp.png)

Comment: hello Vojtěch Šíma , thanks for your answer.
unfortunately establish the connection  relationship between Days Table and Status Table are not possible because these don't  have relationship 
table status have next fields ( maq , Status ,Timestamp) and days table (day) * theyre consecutive numbers 1- 31

Comment: hello Vojtěch Šíma ,  i did some change about od the question. my idea is only get the devices that had same status( off) during all time depending selected day